# Netezza utility NZLOAD to point -df location to the hdfs location

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, netezza

Currently, we are copying the files from hdfs to local and we are using the **NZLOAD** utility to load the data into **Netezza**, but just wanted to know if it is possible to provide the hdfs location of the files as below

```
nzload -host ${NZ_HOST} -u ${NZ_USER} -pw ${NZ_PASS} -db ${NZ_DB} -t ${TAR_TABLE} -df "hdfs://${HDFS_Location}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As HDFS is different file system, nzload will not recognise the file if you provide hdfs file path in -df option of Netezza nzload.

You can use hdfs dfs -cat along with nzload to load Netezza table from hdfs directory.

```
$ hdfs dfs -cat /data/stud_dtls/stud_detls.csv | nzload -host 192.168.1.100 -u admin -pw password -db training -t stud_dtls -delim ','
Load session of table 'STUD_DTLS' completed successfully
```

[Load HDFS file into Netezza Table Using nzload and External Tables](http://dwgeek.com/load-hdfs-file-into-netezza-table-using-nzload-external-tables.html/)